# How to compare two pairwise dissimilarity matrices to see if one of them has higher values?

Tags: matrix, distance

I'm looking for a way **to compare two dissimilarity matrices each having pairwise dissimilarities between the same set of pairs but for different time steps (years in my case) to see if one of them has significantly higher values** in R. A visual representation of the case is given below.

[image]

I'm simply trying to see if the pairwise dissimilarity values have changed between the years. I found out that a simple GLM or a GLMM (see below) have independence issues. The hypothetical example below is for a 5x5 pairwise dissimilarity matrix. Remember, pairwise dissimilarities are calculated **for the same pairs**.

```
dists_2005 # A "dist" object of dissimilarities.
dists_2015 # Another "dist" object of dissimilarities. 

# Ready a data frame of tidy nature for the model construction. Imagine 5x5 matrices.
data <- data.frame(year = as.factor(rep(c(rep("2005", 10), rep("2015", 10)),
                   dissimilarities = c(as.vector(dists_2005), as.vector(dists_2015),
                   pair_id = c(as.factor(rep(rep(paste("X", 1:10, sep = ""), 2))

glm <- glmmTMB(data = data, formula = dissimilarities ~ year, family = family)
glmm <- glmmTMB(data = data, formula = dissimilarities ~ year + (1 | pair_id), family = family)
# The sample sizes are not high enough - the code is only for demonstration purposes.
```

I expect both of these models to produce autocorrelated residuals intuitively, and I also saw that GLMs and GLMMs I produced had problematic `acf()` and `pacf()` plots for some real life data.

**EDIT:** The reason why I expect independence issues is because if there is some change in one of the members (say, "b") all the related pairwise dissimilarities (b-a, b-c, b-d, b-e) will be affected by this, and perhaps in a similar way.

**EDIT 2:** My real-life dissimilarity matrices look like the matrix below.

[image]

My question is: How can I compare the values in my case and test if the dissimilarities are higher/lower in one of the matrices?

Comment: Your distance matrices aren't distances because they are not symmetric (among other reasons).  What exactly is your "distance" function?

Comment: @whuber thanks for the reply. I don't see why they are not symmetric. In my real-life case, they are community (as in ecology) dissimilarity matrices generated by using beta.pair() function from the betapart package. So, should I replace the word "distance" by "dissimilarity"? I think I should.

Comment: *Look* at them!  They are not symmetric; distances between elements and themselves are nonzero; and they don't satisfy the triangle inequality.  In short, they have *none* of the properties of distance matrices apart from containing non-negative values.

Comment: @whuber thanks. I have edited the question and added some more information. I think my sample code was the problem.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  Your real matrix is obviously special: for instance, one distance $0.01515152 = 1/66$ appears many times.  What can you tell us about the nature of the variation in locations between years?  How are those locations measured?  What distance function are you using (evidently not Euclidean!)?  Indeed, it looks like the triangle inequality doesn't hold (check SUG1, SUH2, and SVF1 for instance), so it's still not a distance matrix.

Comment: @whuber thanks to your directions. These are actually community (community: a collection of species) dissimilarities resulting from species turnover (kindly see pages 2 and 3 [https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1466-8238.2009.00490.x] for more information on how the index is calculated) or Simpson's dissimilarities between two communities. The function I'm using is beta.pair() function from the betapart package (kindly see page 6 in [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betapart/betapart.pdf] for more information about the function). Thanks very much.

Comment: @whuber the same values keep popping up because some of those communities have just one species (e.g., SVF1) or they really have the same amount of dissimilarities, so there is not problem with the accuracg of the data.